# Custom directive to Drag and Drop in AngularJS app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive

I have written an application in AngularJS and one of the requirements I am working on is to drag elements from left and drop that element to right container. All the elements from left does get dropped over to right container one by done fine. But when I click on x icon to move them back to left container, I can only move items that are in blue and item ("Manual Intervention") in green color, I cannot move back to left container. I have attached `ng-click` to `a link` to trigger a function to detach all items that are cloned and move items that are not cloned. I think this part `$rootScope.removeDraggedItem` of the code in my js doesnt bind correctly when it is moved from left to right for "Manual Intervention" element and its unable to execute the function.

Here is the link to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nofb7rjp/).

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div class="panel-heading">Components configuration:</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="min-height: 300px;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="">
              <ul class="list-group" id="dropleft">
                <li class="ui-state-default drag-n-drop" drag-option="dropleft" ng-repeat="component in components">
                  <span class="label label-primary">{{component.name}} 
                                                <a href="#" ng-click="$root.removeDraggedItem($event)"><i style="color: white" class="fa fa-times hidden" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                </li>
                <li class="ui-state-default drag-n-drop-clone" drag-option="clone" detach-element>
                  <span class="label label-success">Manual Intervention 
                                                <a href="#" ng-click="$root.removeDraggedItem($event)"><i style="color: white" class="fa fa-times hidden" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                            </span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="jumbotron sortable" id="dropright" style="min-height: 300px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.title = "Test";
  $rootScope.removeDraggedItem = function($event) {
    var element = $(event.target).closest("li");
    console.log(element.attr("drag-option"));
    if (element.attr("drag-option") === "clone") {
      element.detach();
    } else {
      // Move to its original place
      console.log("No clone detected! Moving element to its original place...");
      var attrVal = element.attr("drag-option");
      $(element).find("i").addClass("hidden");
      $(element).detach().appendTo("#" + attrVal);
    }
  };
  $scope.components = [{
    "name": "Component App1"
  }, {
    "name": "Component App2"
  }, {
    "name": "Component App3"
  }, {
    "name": "Component SQL1"
  }, {
    "name": "Component SQL2"
  }];
});
app.directive('dragNDrop', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#dropright",
          revert: function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
              top: 0,
              left: 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
          }
        });
        $('#dropright').droppable({
          drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find("li").find("i").removeClass("hidden");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('detachElement', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AC',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("a").bind('click', function() {
          console.log("working now???");
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('dragNDropClone', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#dropright",
          helper: 'clone',
          invert: false
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('sortable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.sortable({
          cursor: 'move',
          revert: true
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

**CSS:**

```
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/*
    Release Dashboard
*/
.dashboard-header {
    margin-top: 31px;
}

.release-action-btn {
    border-color: #fff;
}

.status-color-red {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    color: white;
}
.status-color-success {
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
.status-color-new {
    background-color: #999999;
    color: white;
}
.status-color-inprogress {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    color: white;
}

.panel-default > .panel-heading, .table-header, .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #164c9c !important;
    color: white;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Fixed the issue by adding on click event to droppable. See below code.

```
$('#dropright').droppable({
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).find("li").find("i").removeClass("hidden");
                            if ($(this).find("li").attr("drag-option") === "clone")
                            {
                                console.log($(this).find("li").find("a"));
                                $(this).find("li").find("a").on('click', function (evt) {
                                    evt.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).closest("li").remove();
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: I do not see the code you use for the `click` event on `<i>` element that is unhidden after drop.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you see parent element of `<i>`, which is `<a>`, you will see `ng-click` to trigger function. The whole `li` gets moved from left to right, which also moves all the child elements as well.

Comment: Do you want the green items to be cloned to the right or moved to the right?

Comment: When I look at consle, I see `Error: event is not defined` when `$root.removeDraggedItem($event)` is fired.

Comment: Found the issue in your fiddle, you had `$event` set as the attribute name. changing it to `event` resolve the error and function operates properly.

Comment: @CodeWarrior, I want the green item to be cloned to the right. And if the cloned item is not needed in right, it must be removed. When I click on x, it doesnt remove green item in right.

Answer (score 1):

Forked you fiddle. I found one issue in this code:

```
  $rootScope.removeDraggedItem = function($event) {
    var element = $(event.target).closest("li");
    console.log(element.attr("drag-option"));
    if (element.attr("drag-option") === "clone") {
      element.detach();
    } else {
      // Move to its original place
      console.log("No clone detected! Moving element to its original place...");
      var attrVal = element.attr("drag-option");
      $(element).find("i").addClass("hidden");
      $(element).detach().appendTo("#" + attrVal);
    }
  };
```

You define the function attribute as `$event` and then call on `event` within the function. I used the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hd234vq8/

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.title = "Test";
  $rootScope.removeDraggedItem = function(event) {
    var element = $(event.target).closest("li");
    console.log(element.attr("drag-option"));
    if (element.attr("drag-option") === "clone") {
      element.detach();
    } else {
      // Move to its original place
      console.log("No clone detected! Moving element to its original place...");
      var attrVal = $("#" + element.attr("drag-option"));
      element.find("i").addClass("hidden");
      var attrPos = attrVal.position();
      element.css("position", "absolute");
      element.animate({
        //top: (attrPos.top + attrVal.find("li:last").height()),
        top: "-=250",
        left: attrPos.left
      }, function() {
        element.detach().appendTo(attrVal);
        element.attr("style", "").css("position", "relative");
      });
    }
  };
  $scope.components = [{
    "name": "Component App1"
  }, {
    "name": "Component App2"
  }, {
    "name": "Component App3"
  }, {
    "name": "Component SQL1"
  }, {
    "name": "Component SQL2"
  }];
});
app.directive('dragNDrop', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#dropright",
          revert: function(event, ui) {
            // on older version of jQuery use "draggable"
            // $(this).data("draggable")
            // on 2.x versions of jQuery use "ui-draggable"
            // $(this).data("ui-draggable")
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
              top: 0,
              left: 0
            };
            // return boolean
            return !event;
            // that evaluate like this:
            // return event !== false ? false : true;
          }
        });
        $('#dropright').droppable({
          drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find("li").find("i").removeClass("hidden");
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('detachElement', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AC',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("a").bind('click', function() {
          console.log("working now???");
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('dragNDropClone', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#dropright",
          helper: 'clone',
          invert: false
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('sortable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.sortable({
          cursor: 'move',
          revert: true
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

If a user drags an item to another list, I like to animate the return. You will see this in the code above.

**Update**

Per your update, I suggest the following in droppable:

```
$('#dropright').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var item = $(this).find("li");
    item.find("i").removeClass("hidden");
    if (item.attr("drag-option") === "clone") {
      console.log(item.find("a"));
      item.find("a").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        item.remove();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This will be a good option to ensure that there is a callback bound to the event. You can use `.click()` here since you're assigning it directly. If you were assigning it before the element existed, you could use `.on()`. Ether way is still going to work.

One other thing I noticed, is that within `#dropright`, there is no `<ul>` element. This is not an issue, yet it does come across as odd. Felt it was worth mentioning.

Comment: When green item was cloned to right, I was unable to remove that item from right. Is that working for you?

Comment: Will have to test. Suspect that click callback is not cloned.

Comment: Finished testing, I see `if (element.attr("drag-option") === "clone") { element.detach(); }` for this item. Do you want the cloned item to be removed or added back to the original list as an extra item?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time helping me with this :) I want the cloned item to be removed as the original list already has that list.

Comment: @Ray then I would use `if (element.attr("drag-option") === "clone") { element.remove(); }`

Comment: I tried that in my solution. That didnt work as well. I think the problem is that event doesnt get registered in dom when it is cloned and angular cannot understand what to do with it.

Comment: @Ray it also looks like this event is not firing. It fires for the other items, but not the green one. You'll want to sort that out.

Comment: @Ray yes,that would make since since the event callback is written before the element exists. Since it's created dynamically, the callback has to be assigned using `.on()` before hand or bound at the time it's created.

Comment: Alright. I think I fixed the issue by adding an event to `droppable`. See `update` at the very end of my original question.